# TOTP Problem/Bug

Tags: google-chrome, two-factor-authentication, password

I've recently joined a new company, and my corporate login requires an additional TOTP.

I've tried using the same QR code generated for the TOPT on several TOTP generators, and have had mixed results:

- [Authenticator extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/authenticator/bhghoamapcdpbohphigoooaddinpkbai?hl=enhttps://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/authenticator/bhghoamapcdpbohphigoooaddinpkbai?hl=en) for Google Chrome, **invalid** TOTP
- 1Password extension for Google Chrome, **invalid** TOTP
- 1Password app for macOS, **valid** TOTP
- 1Password app for iOS, **valid** TOTP
- Google Authenticator app for iOS, **valid** TOTP

Google Chrome is running on the same Macbook as 1Password, and both the date/time values on my iPhone and Macbook are being synchronised with an NTP server.

Does anyone have any idea why the TOTPs generated are all invalid when using Google Chrome extensions?

Comment: I've had amazing success with all manner of one time password and the 1Password app. Have you dug into the specific error and reached out to their support? My guess would be this is a procedural or time setting error but hard to tell without specific details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After checking with the respective teams supporting 1Password and Authenticator, it has been determined that the invalid TOTP generated was due to how the 'period' parameter was being handled.

The 1Password team has released a new version of their extension, and I've verified it to work perfectly, and a feature request has been raised in the Authenticator GitHub repo.